# Android Studio: Use "OnClick" Method in different Activity?

Tags: java, android, methods

I've created the android:onClick-method **"showHiddenText"** to expand different Buttons with a switch case inside two Dialogs.

Button-Example:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/product_description_Btn"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_width="350sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_lightblue_normal"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingTop="7sp"
                android:text="@string/product_information_descriptionBtn"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:onClick="showHiddenText"
                android:fontFamily="@font/louis_bold"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandable_view_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/lighter_grey"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_margin="10sp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_text_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/louis_bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/product_consumptionadvice_Btn"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_width="350sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_lightblue_normal"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingTop="7sp"
                android:text="@string/product_information_consumptionadviceBtn"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:onClick="showHiddenText"
                android:fontFamily="@font/louis_bold"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandable_view_product_consumptionadvice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/lighter_grey"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_margin="10sp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_text_product_consumptionadvice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ConsumptionAdvice"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/louis_bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>
```

The Buttons which open up these Dialog are called "Product-Information" and "Manufactorer-Information"

I've created this method in a **Activity A**, where the Buttons are reachable.

But now I've created another **Activity B**, where the Buttons are reachable as well to do the exact same thing.

showHiddenText-Code:

```
public void showHiddenText(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        //----------------------------------PRODUKT-INFORMATIONEN-----------------------------------------------------//
        case R.id.product_description_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_description);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_description_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.product_consumptionadvice_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_product_consumptionadvice);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_consumptionadvice_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.product_ingredients_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_product_ingredients);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_ingredients_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.product_nutritionvalues_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_product_nutritionvalues);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_nutritionvalues_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.product_bestbefore_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_product_bestbefore);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_bestbefore_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.product_allergies_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_product_allergies);
            expand_Btn = (Button) product_info_view.findViewById(R.id.product_allergies_Btn);
            break;

        //----------------------------------HERSTELLER-INFORMATIONEN-----------------------------------------------------//
        case R.id.manufactorer_info_name_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_manufactorer_name);
            expand_Btn = (Button) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_name_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.manufactorer_info_production_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_manufactorer_production);
            expand_Btn = (Button) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_production_Btn);
            break;


        case R.id.manufactorer_info_animals_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_manufactorer_animals);
            expand_Btn = (Button) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_animals_Btn);
            break;

        case R.id.manufactorer_info_contact_Btn:
            expandable_CardView = (CardView) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_cardview);
            expandable_View = (LinearLayout) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view_manufactorer_contact);
            expand_Btn = (Button) manufactorer_info_view.findViewById(R.id.manufactorer_info_contact_Btn);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    ExpandView(expand_Btn, expandable_View);

}

public void ExpandView(Button ExpandButton, LinearLayout ExpandView){

    if (ExpandView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(expandable_CardView, new AutoTransition());
        ExpandView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ExpandButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_up_24);
    }
    else {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(expandable_CardView, new AutoTransition());
        ExpandView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ExpandButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24);
    }
}
```

Without creating the Method "showHiddenText" again, I got the Error

***Could not find method showHiddenText(View) in a parent or ancestor Context für android:onClick attribute defined on view class.....***

So my question is:

Is there a way, to get access to this onClick-method in Activtiy A? Or do I have to implement the method again in Activity B?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please add actual code others can see and copy

Answer (score 0):

1. You could create extension for Activity if you are using Kotlin.
2. You can create BaseActivity with this method.
3. You can create Helper class with this method.

There are many ways to achieve it.

Comment: Hmm.. with BaseActivity you mean like an Activtiy where all my methods and variables, which I need in several different Activitys are created?

Comment: Yeah something like that. Imho it's not recommended option becouse BaseActivity could became a "GodActivity"